# FAIL - Application at context path /CONTROL could not be started

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat

I have a problem when I try to deploy my WAR file web application on tomcat 7. It was working yesterday but I think there is problem in the web.xml. I have tried to press start button but getting this message:

> FAIL - Application at context path /CONTROL could not be started

Can anyone help me?

web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee ;http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.examples.view.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<!-- Set the login filter to secure all the pages in the /secured/ * path 
    of the application -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/secured/ *</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- By default go to secured welcome page -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>secured/welcome.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<filter>
    <filter-name>urlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.examples.view.UrlRewriteFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>urlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/ *</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See
        JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext
    </param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>custom-theme</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

LOG file :

```
http://sams-app.com/catalina.out
```

Comment: how do i get Stacktrace from server .. note i'm using real web hosting

Comment: Ask for it to your web hosting service provider.

Comment: i'm the web hosting .

Comment: Then look for a log file where you can refer to the stacktrace of the errors when deploying the application.

Comment: can you give me path to Log file cuz i don't know how to find it . thank you

Comment: Go to your tomcat installation path, then to the log folder. Seriously, that's part of your job.

Comment: i have added the log file

Answer (score -2):

I see that some part of your web.xml appears to be commented. It appears in grey.Is the one you posted appears to be same in your work environment also. Below is the part which appears to be in grey.

---

```xml
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
<description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF   
Specification 2.5.2</description>
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
<param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
<param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
<param-value>custom-theme</param-value>
 </context-param>
  <filter>
<filter-name>urlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.primefaces.examples.view.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>urlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

<filter>
<filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.primefaces.examples.view.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
    <!-- Set the login filter to secure all the pages in the /secured/* path of 
the     application  -->
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/secured/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

 <!-- By default go to secured welcome page -->
 <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>secured/welcome.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: That was just the format. The only things commented in the web.xml are comments. I've added the formatting for this XML code as well.

Comment: i have added the log file